# Java:How to read file and get how many times the values appear?

Tags: java

I have a .txt file as below,

Red,AppSample

Yellow,AppSample

Yellow,AppSample

Green,AppExample

Here string before ","represents the status and string after "," represnts the application name.As and 
when the updates are received the same is written in file.Now while 
displaying the status of application I need to take the highest priority which is Red.For that first I need to 
get all status for application updated and then read the status and take status with highest 
priorty and the application name. Not getting how can this be done.Hope I am clear.
In the below code I have taken application name as String.Then I am reading the whole file and creating a string.Not sure whats needs to be done then.........

```
String element="AppSample"

File file = new File("a.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
fis.read(data);
fis.close();
//
String s = new String(data, "UTF-8");

if(s.contians(element){ ???Then.....
```

Comment: you may use the readLines method of FileUtils http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File, java.nio.charset.Charset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use BufferedReader.

```
BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String currentLine;
                        int count;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a.txt"));

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null && currentLine.contains("AppSample")) {
                count++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

System.out.println("Count: "+count);
```

EDIT:
See other answers recommendig to use split(). This was the answer to your question before you edited it. To determine the Red,Yellow,Green status you probably should split the lines at ",".

Answer (score 1):

Use a reader e.g. `BufferedReader` and read your file line by line.

Then you can split each line using String's split method.

This will make your task much easier.

See here for more details.

[BufferedReader.readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

[String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)